# Why is 'heroku create' doing nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku

I opened a heroku account.
I followed the instructions on http://docs.heroku.com/quickstart.
I have a working rails app which I have deployed successfully elsewhere.
I have a github account that works.
I have a local git repository for my rails app.
I installed the heroku gem.  It shows up in my gem list.
I typed 'heroku create' at the command prompt...
My command console showed that it was thinking about it, but did nothing.  No errors. No action.

Possible related facts:  I am using a Windows 7 machine.  I have also failed miserably at deploying with capistrano with a similar--issue command, get no response--pattern.

Comment: Are you issuing the command in your application folder?

Comment: Yep.  And it just hangs and hangs and hangs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure now that its a windows issue.  Since I posted this I installed Ubuntu via VirtualBox on the same machine.  I ran heroku create on the same app through a ruby/rails there and it worked as expected.

Comment: Heroku is a commercial company. You could ask support there. Heroku guys know about the gem better than anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure now that it's a Windows issue. I don't know what exactly, it could be that the heroku gem doesn't support a Windows environment very well, or it could be something else. 
However, since my original post I installed Ubuntu via VirtualBox on the same machine. From that installation I ran heroku create on the same app and it worked as expected.

Comment: so what is alternative about this.

Comment: This is a 12 year old issue that involves rapidly evolving technology.  Not sure you should rely on anything here in 2022